# Different content for each Spinner item in the same Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner

How can I show different content after selecting an item from the `Spinner`?
I want to create a `Spinner` with locations of chain stores.

Comment: What exactly means *Even after choosing the Adress I still want the spinner to be visible and show all the locations.*?

Comment: I want the spinner to be always there on top. The only thing that changes to be the content under the spinner

Comment: 1 item of the spinner = 1 adress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the spinner to be always there on top. The only thing that
>   changes to be the content under the spinner

Create a simple method in your activity to refresh the layout below the `Spinner`(which will remain untouched). That method will be called from a `OnItemSelectedListener` set on the `Spinner`. It would be something like this:

```
private void changeAdress(int newSelectedAdress) {
    // The ImageView and the TextView will be already in the layout
    ImageView map = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.theIdOfTheImage);
    // Set the image. You know the current address selected by the user
    // (the newSelectedAddress int) so get it from the array/list/database
    // where you stored it
    // also set the image
}
```

Called the method above from the `onItemSelected` callback:

```
yourSpinnerRefference.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                          changeAddress(position);              
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

If this is not what you want, please explain.

Edit: Make two arrays to hold your data:

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.imag1, R.drawable.imag2 ..etc...};
//also for the text
String[] text = {"text1", "text2 ...etc...};
```

Then use those two arrays in the method I recommended above:

```
private void changeAdress(int newSelectedAddress) {
     ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mapView1)).setImageResource(images[newSelectedAddress]); 
     // assing an id to the TextView in your layout and do the same as above.
}
```

There is no need for multiple `ImageView` and `TextViews`.

Comment: I am noob in programming so I while looking at your code I try to understand how I can implement how I want.

Comment: onItemSelected { if int = 0 -> Show Image1,Text1 ; If int= 1 -> Show Image2;Text2 ... all in the same activity . That's how I want to do it

Comment: @CatalinH Yes in the `changeAddress` method you'll look at the `newSelectedAdress` parameter. If it is `1` you load the first address, if it's `2` you load the second address etc. I don't know how you store those address, if you have them in an array for example then you would simply get the item at the index `newSelectedAdress` from that array. I've edited my answer a bit.

Comment: I am sorry but I am still lost. I edited my question and I added the class code and the xml. I wrote some details in the code of what I need to do. Can you please help me figure this out?

Comment: Figured it out. Needed an ImageView and TextView for every int position. And for ImageView needed also: img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image); Thank you Luksprog.

Comment: @CatalinH Not really. I didn't say to use an `ImageView` and `TextView` for every position. Use your current layout file and see my edited answer.

Comment: I changed the code the way you said, no errors but the images and text are not displayed.

Comment: @CatalinH I don't see why that would happen. Did you also called the `changeAddress` method from the `onItemSelected` callback?

Comment: It finally worked, seems I didn't wrote it as I should of. But the text is on multiple lines, how can  I do to add the text but without overwrite the array. Ex how I need: http://www.bmw.ro/ro/ro/general/ecom_uib/dlo/bmw_dealers.html